# using a templated key in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unordered-map

I don't understand why my compiler won't accept code below

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T>
using M = std::unordered_set<T>;

template<class T>
using D = M<T>;

template<class T>
using DM = std::unordered_map < typename M<T>::const_iterator    // Problem
                              , typename D<T>::const_iterator >; // Problem

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    D<int> d;
    M<int> m;
    DM<int> dm; // Problem
}
```

The compiler command is

```
clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test
```

A compiler error message excerpt is

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:85:11: error: 
      implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::hash<std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<int, true, false> >'
        noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
```

Why isn't it allowed to use `typename M<T>::const_iterator` as key in `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Also, I do not think those `typename`s are required since both `M` and `D` are not template parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the default template argument for hash of [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), which doesn't provide implementation for iterator.

You need to provide use-defined hash for it, such as

```
struct iterator_hash {
    template <typename I>
    std::size_t operator()(const I &i) const {
        return std::hash<int>()(*i); // or return sth based on i
    }
};
```